# WPF - How to dock a Border onto a Canvas?

Tags: wpf, layout, canvas, dock

I have a Border inside a Canvas. The Border's height/width are varying according to its contents. I want the Border to stretch out to fill up the entire Canvas. How can I do that?

I have tried this on the Border without success:

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=MainCanvas, Path=Height}" 
Width="{Binding ElementName=MainCanvas, Path=Width}"
```

Comment: Why don't you just put the Canvas inside the Border? Then you wouldn't even have to do the extra binding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does the canvas have an explicit height/width? It may be auto sizing and have a height/width of double.NaN.

Try binding the child height/width to the ActualHeight and ActualWidth of canvas like so:

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=MainCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
Width="{Binding ElementName=MainCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Canvas Panels never tell children to size relative to their size, even when the children are set to HorizontalAlignment.Stretch (or vertical). So binding is a good solution here.

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh! I needed ActualHeight/ActualWidth as opposed to Height/Width.